# Bot Framework Typescript / NodeJS Safe to Skip Optional NPM Dependencies?

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework

We're trying to get a Typescript / Node bot to build in Team City. We're using the Typescript version of the bot framework. We don't have Python or the C++ build tools on the build server, so all the packages that require node-gyp fail to install and the whole build fails.

I notice that if I run npm install --no-optional, then it doesn't seem to depend on any packages that require node-gyp / Python, and builds OK. The resulting code seems to run OK to at first glance.

I was wondering if this is likely to break any functionality in the bot framework? AKA "is it safe"?

Maybe some edge case somewhere? They are optional packages but presumably there is a reason they were there in the first place. They're not directly included from the main project but are nested dependencies.

I'm from a C# background so the notion of an optional dependency in the first place is a bit weird to me!

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 2):

Optional dependencies are often safe to ignore since they are meant to specify dependencies that aren't needed for functionality. That being said however, there are some packages which have optional dependencies that are needed for a specific part of their functionality though that is not the norm.

Optional dependencies are often used for things like [fsevents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) which are OS dependent, thus can only be installed in certain environments.

For more info, the [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies) from NPM on optionalDepenencies.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I guess I now need advice on the specific optional packages the bot framework uses and whether it's been seen in the real world as safe to skip them.